# how to find string which has number

Tags: regex, apache-spark, hive

I want to find string which has number using spark.

```
Example : String = "abc def ghi2 xyz4"
Answer : ghi2 xyz4
```

Comment: Hive or Spark? Make a choice please.

Comment: Do you specifically mean any words in the string that have at least one numeric character? Anywhere in the word? Or specifically at the end? Any number of digits or just a single digit?

Comment: @thebluephantom spark

Comment: @DannyStaple it can be anywhere and can be more numbers in string

Comment: answer below I see

Comment: @thebluephantom can you please give more easy answer

Answer (score 1):

```
+-----------------+
|            value|
+-----------------+
|abc def ghi2 xyz4|
| 0d2 234 AXZ Mxei|
+-----------------+

Seq("abc def ghi2 xyz4","0d2 234 AXZ Mxei").toDF()
.select('*,monotonically_increasing_id.as("id"))
.select('id,explode(split('value," ")))
.select('*,regexp_extract('col,"\\d",0).as("digit"))
.filter('digit.notEqual(""))
.groupBy('id)
.agg(concat_ws(" ",collect_list('col)).as("value"))
.show()
```

output

```
+---+---------+
| id|    value|
+---+---------+
|  0|ghi2 xyz4|
|  1|  0d2 234|
+---+---------+
```

or using RDD:

```
Seq("abc def ghi2 xyz4","0d2 234 AXZ Mxei").toDF().rdd.map(s=>s.getString(0).split(" ").filter(s=>s.matches(".*\\d.*")))
```

Comment: Can you please give easy answer.

Comment: The answer is fine, I upvoted it as the person was quicker than me. This is how Spark tends to work.

Comment: @NaveenGupta I added RDD solution.

Comment: RDD is surprisingly very short and easy solution. Thanks

Comment: Why we used getString(0). what exactly is doing. I have checked but can't any difference just converting df to dataset.

Comment: `.toDF()` creates Dataset<Row>, after `.rdd` call you have RDD<Row> and to get *first* column as a string you should call that function `getString(0)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the input to Seq
2. Add where clause with regex + `rlike` function to check for digits
3. Map to String `.map(row => row.getString(0))`
4. Concatenate and output the string

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object CheckDigitInString {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = "abc def ghi2 xyz4"
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    import spark.implicits._
    val inputDf = input.split(" ").toSeq.toDF

    val output = inputDf.where(col("value").rlike(".*[0-9]+.*"))
      .map(row => row.getString(0))
      .collect().mkString(" ")
    println(output)
  }

}
```